# When do we say "on the land" and "in the land"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

According to my study, it seems that we use "**on**" with  "**land**" when "**land**" means "*the surface of the earth that is not sea*", and we use "**in**" "**land**" when "**land**" means "*a country or region in a way that involves the emotions or the imagination*".

Example 1, *Some animals can live both on land and in water.* ("**land**" here means "*the surface of the earth that is not sea*")

But we don't often say "**on the land**" but just "**on land**".

But say, I am swimming in a river then

should I say "**let's get on land**" or "**get on the land**" or "**get on the ground**"?

Example 2, "*She was all alone in a strange land.*" ("**land**" means "*a country or region in a way that involves the emotions or the imagination*")

In Snow White story, the evil stepmom asks to her mirror "*Who is the fairest in all the lands*"?

When do we say "**on the land**" and "**in the land**"?

Comment: If you were swimming in a river or the sea you would probably say "Let's get out [of the water]", or "Let's get ashore" rather than mentioning the land. Swimmers don't usually go far from the shore. Only people on ships talk about returning to land.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*in the land*" is usually followed by the name of a country or region, and is used to mean within that country. For example:

> - In the land of Oz, strange an magical things happen.
> - In the land of Russia, there is a long tradition of authoritarianism.
> - In the land of Mongolia, ther is no longer an independent government.

This form ism more often used with old names for countries that no longer exist, or for fictional countries, or for poetic usage. It can also be used for figurative or poetic terms form an area, for example "*the land of the rising sun*" for Japan, or "*the land of the Midnight Sun*" for the area north of the Arctic circle. In modern, factual uses, "country of" is much more common.

"*in the land*" can also be used to mean "in the soil" as in "there is a lot of clay in the land of this region".

"*On the land*" is often used to refer to farmers and otehr agricultural workers. In other cases it often refers to the physical surface, as in "There are a lot of rocks on the land in this area".

"*on the laND